# eclipse e4 remove gaps between parts

Tags: eclipse, e4

can I somehow remove the gaps between the parts in an eclispe e4 application. There is always a couple of pixes (like 5 or so) gap where the background color can be seen between my tabs. However, I need the full space for the parts and thus want to get rid of this gap. 
I tried already with css-properties (margin and padding) set on CTabFolder and MPart without success..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the shadow on the part stack removes most of the space:.

The padding for the part stack adjusts the space inside the border.

```css
.MPartStack 
{
    swt-shadow-visible: false;

    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px
}
```

Comment: well this still leaves a 5px gap. I use the parts as a video display and it looks arkward to have this gap between two videos

Comment: I think the remaining space is for the Sash control between the tabs created by the PartSashContainer renderer. So either don't use PartSashContainer in the application model or write a custom Sash Renderer.